# Store value from nested for loop with two separate variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels

I am currently looking to store variables created in a nested for loop:

```
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y, order=param, seasonal_order=param_seasonal, enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
        results = mod.fit()
```

In the above example I need to get the `param` and `param_seasonal` which generate the best result. I have been trying different data structures but haven't been able to find anything that works let alone is pythonic.

The outcome I'm looking for is a way to get the best result from `mod` and be able to use the corresponding `param` and `param_seasonal`to use as arguments in a different function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do parameter tuning, I store the results either in a dictionary or a dataframe, but mostly dataframes because you are more flexible with further processing (ofc you could create a dataframe from a dictionary later on as well).

```
import pandas as pd
df_parameter_tuning = pd.DataFrame()
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y, order=param, seasonal_order=param_seasonal, enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
        results = mod.fit()
        df_parameter_tuning = df_parameter_tuning.append(pd.DataFrame([[param_seasonal, results]],columns=["params", "results"]))
```

You can then get the best results/parameters by looking up the index of the best parameter like this:

```
print(df_parameter_tuning.loc[df_parameter_tuning["results"].argmax()])
```

The advantage of this is, that you can explore other parameters and their results as well, like plotting them to see patterns or other datapoints to explore.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your question is correct then the below example should do the trick

imagine

- a is param
- b is param_seasonal
- ans is mod

```py
def example_func(a, b):
    return(-a-b+(a**2)+(b**2))

best_score = 0
best_a = 0
best_b = 0

for a in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    for b in [5,6,7,8]:
        
        answer =  example_func(a, b)
        
        if answer > best_score:
            best_score = answer
            best_a = a
            best_b = b
        
print(best_score)      
print(best_a)
print(best_b)
```

output is

```
68
4
8
```

which means that 68 was the best value and was calculated with a=4 and b=8.

This works assuming that the higher the answer the better but can be easily modified if lower is better.

You can then just use best_a and best_b outside and below the for loops to pass in the desired variables to whatever function you want